# I have downloaded my laravel project from cpanel. But its all stylesheets and asset not working on localhost

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, assets

I have downloaded my laravel project from cpanel. But its all stylesheets,js and asset not working on localhost. When I serve application and run on browser. Page shows but all assets like js stylesheets saying 404 not found on console..

I have provided path  asset('public/css/stylesheet.css') or URl::asset('public/path...')
When I remove public from path it load but I want to work it as now because it is working live.

There is also an index.php on root.

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 */

$uri = urldecode(
  parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
  return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Here is my root .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 400
   php_value max_input_time 400
   php_value max_input_vars 5000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 400
   php_value max_input_time 400
   php_value max_input_vars 5000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Server.php is same as index.php

here is .htaccess in public folder

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes



RewriteEngine On



# Handle Authorization Header

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]



# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$

RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]



# Handle Front Controller...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/

RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

and this is index.php in public

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: check .env file contains right APP_URL value. like `APP_URL=http://localhost`

Comment: Yes this is just like that you say APP_URL=http://localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with these following steps
1- pasted htaccess and index.php from the public to project root

2- then in server.php removed modify these line as follows

```
    require_once(__DIR__'./index.php');
     file_exists(__DIR__.$uri);
```

3- in index.php change require link as follows

```
    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

4- then in appserviceprovider.php in register method add this

```
          $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path();
            });
```